Is there an equivalent apiCallTimeout in the Javascript sdkv3?
In the Java sdk, there is the apiCallTimeout: https://sdk.amazonaws.com/java/api/latest/software/amazon/awssdk/core/client/config/ClientOverrideConfiguration.Builder.html#apiCallTimeout(java.time.Duration)
Described as:

Configure the amount of time to allow the client to complete the execution of an API call. This timeout covers the entire client execution except for marshalling. This includes request handler execution, all HTTP requests including retries, unmarshalling, etc. This value should always be positive, if present.

When looking at this javascript sdkv3 upgrading guide:
https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-js-v3/blob/main/UPGRADING.md
It mentions timeouts as:

connectTimeout
v2: Sets the socket to timeout after failing to establish a connection with the server after connectTimeout milliseconds.
v3: connectionTimeout is available in NodeHttpHandler options.

timeout
v2: The number of milliseconds a request can take before automatically being terminated.
v3: socketTimeout is available in NodeHttpHandler options.


But the docs: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/v3/latest/Package/-smithy-node-http-handler/Interface/NodeHttp2HandlerOptions/
Seem to be on an individual connection level, and not a total timeout including all retries. So is it possible to set a timeout on the api calls similar to how Java can with apiCallTimeout?
